# change collation of DB SQL Server 2008

Tags: collation, sql-server-2008-express

I have created some new databases in SQL Server 2008 Express (10.0.1600.22) and I have also restored one from SQL Server 2005 Express (9.00.1399.06).

The collations for these are different and I cannot execute queries across them as a result. So I am trying to change the restored database collation

```
from: SQL_Latin1_Genral_CP1_CI_AS
to:   Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

However the new collation does not appear in the list of options. Not sure if this is possible.

BTW - workarounds that are not options:

- I cannot script the data from sql server 2005 express (it seems - I may be missing something)
- I cannot script the DB on 2K8 server as I get an out of memory exception when doing that :-(

Comment: Maybe try changing the compatibility mode of the restored database to 100 to see if it appears in the list of options?

Comment: "does not appear in list of options" mean I right click on DB>properties>options> collation drop down.

Comment: I tried this, I thought it was working but it was a mistake.  I have now set the collation to be "Latin1_General_CI_AS" on the restored DB but i still get the following error message:

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: I have changed the collation of the DB but I am now needing to change the columns individually.  I think I will post another question about doing that...

Comment: @Martin, sorry if you post your comment as a an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the collation is visible for other databases on your instance but not this specific one restored from a 2005 instance I wonder if the list displayed is dependent upon the databases compatibility model.

Maybe try changing the compatibility mode of the restored database to 100 to see if it appears in the list of options.

Note changing the database collation will not affect existing columns. [Here's a script that may help with that](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/piotr_rodak/archive/2007/12/14/changing-collation-of-all-columns-without-dropping-them.aspx).