# SQL Server - best strategy to change database collation on 1 database (not change server default)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Question: is there an effective way to switch the collation of 1 database in SQL Server?

I've set the collation of the database through properties -> options -> collation. Although this collation is set for new fields, none of the existing text-based fields in the database are being changed. This is what I need to get done.

The database on which I need to switch the collation is huge (50+GB, 750+ tables) so manually changing all fields in the database is not an option.

What about the following:

- create scripts for the structure of the database
- export all data
- drop the database
- create an empty database with the correct collation
- create database structure - all text based fields should now be set
  to the database default
- import data
- Bada bing, bada boom?

Other strategies?

Could I query the master database and change the collations there?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5002081/15498) contains a link to a blog post on [changing collation of all columns without dropping them](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/piotr_rodak/archive/2007/12/14/changing-collation-of-all-columns-without-dropping-them.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but performing such a task by "trial and error" really is not an option - the database simply is to big and this strategy would take me forever.

Comment: Hi @NicoBeemster did you find a solution ? I'm facing same problem

Comment: It's been a while, can't remember. But have a look at the export/import trick. Might help you. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

I faced that problem before and the only way I found was the save-drop-load and populate that database.

Also, I guess you've already browsed this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I've already browsed that page. 

I'm gonna try out this export/ import strategy as this appears to be the most elegant, efficient solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could conceivably create a bunch of queries which will produce rows like "Alter table [schema].[TableName] alter column [ColName] [type] collate [New Collation] [nullability]" as output. This can be done using the built in sys.Schemas, sys.Tables and sys.Columns system views.

Sample:

```
select 'alter table [' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + '] alter column [' + c.name 
    + '] nvarchar(' + CAST(c.max_length/2 as nvarchar) +') ' 
    + ' collate Finnish_Swedish_CI_AI ' 
    + (case when c.is_nullable = 1 then ' null ' else ' not null ' end) 
from sys.tables t
    join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.type='U' and c.system_type_id = 231
```

The sample will find columns of type nvarchar([length]) and produce alter statements to change the collation to Finnish_Swedish_CI_AI.

Note that this sample is meant as a **proof of concept only**. If you want to explore this possible solution you must put some time into studying the mentioned system views.

You would likely have to make separate queries for handling nvarchar, nchar, ntext and varchar, char, text fields. Nvarchar/Varchar(max) fields might need special consideration, as well as any potential computed columns of character type.

Comment: Doh. While I was typing my answer Damien posted a comment with a link to a page where the same strategy was explained. Now I don't know if I should remove my answer or not...

Comment: This is a starting point.  I'm examining the scripts on this page: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic820675-146-1.aspx in an effort to write my own fully automated script.